# How to change embedded tomcat connector port using spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

we can easily change the server port in spring boot application by writing

server.port=8080

but how can i change connector-port? if i cant change the connector port so is there any other way to do it in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this option should be available through `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` (it provides many options for customizing ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer directly) , for this:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

    // ! assume this should be possible using this factory
    factory.setPort(9000);
    factory.setSessionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    return factory;
}
```